# Invalid double: "" when calling EditText, but not on from others in the same method

Tags: java, android

So I'm getting some errors when trying to execute my code.
I have two checkboxes to hide/show certain fields for the user to input data.

This is that snippet of code:

```
public void checkBoxes(View v){
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.IKnowInterest);
        CheckBox checkBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.IKnowYears);
        EditText interest = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.YearlyInterestField);
        EditText yearsToSave = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.YearsToSaveField);
        if (checkBox.isChecked()){
            interest.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            yearsToSave.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        if (checkBox1.isChecked()){
            interest.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            yearsToSave.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }


    }
```

Depending on wether or not one or the other box is checked I call two different methods(Don't mind the code in this, I'm just playing around with these for now):

```
private double iKnowYears(double M, double P, double s, double q, double n){
        double i =0;
        double A;
        n = 25;
        while(true){
            i=i+0.01;
            A = (P*(Math.pow(1+(i/q), (n*q)))) + (M*((Math.pow((1+(i/q)), (n*q) ))-1) * (q / i));
            if (((A*i)-A) >= 12*s){
                break;
            }
        }
        return i;
    }

    private double iKnowInterest(double M, double P, double s, double q, double i){
        double n = 0;
        double A;
        while(true){
            A = (P*(Math.pow(1+(i/q), (n*q)))) + (M*((Math.pow((1+(i/q)), (n*q) ))-1) * (q / i));
            if ((A*i)-A >= 12*s){
                break;
            }
            n++;
        }
        return n;
    }
```

Now this is the part that throws the error:

```
public void moneyVsSalary(View v){
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.IKnowInterest);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Calculate);
        EditText salary = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.SalaryField);
        EditText initialInvestment = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.InitialInvestmentField);
        EditText monthlyInvestment = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.MonthlyDepositField);
        EditText interest = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.YearlyInterestField);
        EditText yearsToSave = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.YearsToSaveField);
        double s = Double.parseDouble(salary.getText().toString());
        double P = Double.parseDouble(initialInvestment.getText().toString());
        double M = Double.parseDouble(monthlyInvestment.getText().toString());
        double q = 12;
        double n = Double.parseDouble(yearsToSave.getText().toString());
        double i = Double.parseDouble(interest.getText().toString())/100;
        //Checks if either interest och year checkboxes are checked.
        if (checkBox.isChecked()){
            button.setText(Double.toString(iKnowInterest(M, P, s, q, i)) + " years");
        }
        else{
            button.setText(Double.toString(iKnowYears(M, P, s, q, n)) + " % per year");
        }
    }
```

Depending on boxes checked it's either `double n = Double.parseDouble(yearsToSave.getText().toString());` or `double i = Double.parseDouble(interest.getText().toString())/100;` that throws the error.

I've been trying to figure out why these throw errors when the rest of the statements don't.
This is the code for the XML part:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.segmeier.financecalc.SalaryVSMoneyYield"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/SalaryField"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:hint="@string/salary_today"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/InitialInvestmentField"
        android:layout_below="@+id/SalaryField"
        android:hint="@string/starting_amount"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/MonthlyDepositField"
        android:layout_below="@+id/InitialInvestmentField"
        android:hint="@string/monthly_installments"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/YearlyInterestField"
        android:layout_below="@+id/YearsToSaveField"
        android:hint="@string/interest_per_year"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/YearsToSaveField"
        android:layout_below="@+id/MonthlyDepositField"
        android:hint="@string/years_to_save"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/calculate"
        android:id="@+id/Calculate"
        android:layout_below="@+id/YearlyInterestField"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="moneyVsSalary" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/iknowhowmanyyearsIWantToSave"
        android:id="@+id/IKnowYears"
        android:layout_above="@+id/InitialInvestmentField"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/InitialInvestmentField"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/InitialInvestmentField"
        android:checked="false"
        android:onClick="checkBoxes"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/IKnowInterest"
        android:id="@+id/IKnowInterest"
        android:layout_above="@+id/IKnowYears"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/InitialInvestmentField"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/InitialInvestmentField"
        android:checked="false"
        android:onClick="checkBoxes"/>


</RelativeLayout >
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: "" is not a numerical value, and thus can not be parsed to a double. It seems to me like interest.getText() returns an empty String

Comment: @Stultuske Why would that part not return a string when the others return just fine? I'm inputing data in all fields.

Comment: Gurkmeja: I have no idea. but why don't you study basic Java before going to android? and, if you know basic Java, why do you call toString on a String ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JTextField` interest or yearsToSave is empty, depending on the checkbox, so only get the relevant value if the checkbox is checked. Change your code like this:

```
 //Checks if either interest och year checkboxes are checked.
 if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
     double i = Double.parseDouble(interest.getText().toString())/100;
     button.setText(Double.toString(iKnowInterest(M, P, s, q, i)) + " years");
 } else {
     double n = Double.parseDouble(yearsToSave.getText().toString());
     button.setText(Double.toString(iKnowYears(M, P, s, q, n)) + " % per year");
 }
```

Comment: I changed my code to what you suggested and I'm not getting an error anymore.

I instead don't get anything and the activity just freezes when i press the "calculate" button. But that's another problem and I think I can solve that on my own :)

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

`Double.parseDouble(...)` throws an Exception when no double is found in the passed String.

---

According to the Java docs (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String)), `Double.parseDouble(String)` can throw the following two exceptions:

NullPointerException - if the string is null

NumberFormatException - if the string does not contain a parsable double.

---

I suggest that you check if the passed String is null or empty, before calling these two lines that throw an Exception.

Comment: Thanks for your input.
It seems like I don't get a String returned from either of these lines. But why? I get returns fine from the earlier EditTexts.

Comment: Maybe the Strings are actually empty?